# Trying to show my Twitter followers count on my website with no luck

Tags: php, twitter

This is the code I am using, but it does return blank in most cases.

```
<?php
$xml=file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=MyTwitterUsernameBla');
if (preg_match('/followers_count>(.*)</',$xml,$match)!=0) {
$count = $match[1];
}
echo $count;
?>
```

I want to show Twitter followers count in simple way, no plugins..it's a website, and not a blog.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works on your localhost but not on your public host, then chances are that Twitter is either blocking or throttling your public server's IP. Many shared hosts get blocked/throttled because there are multiple sites banging away at the Twitter API without authentication. Twitter views them as one app and throttles the IP as a whole.

To get around this, you're going to need to authenticate using oAuth. It's a pain in the ass, but it's a necessary step. Here are some resources that you might find to be handy:

- http://blog.evandavey.com/2010/02/how-to-php-oauth-twitter.html
- http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_OAuth/redirected

Twitter offers you some credentials in the "Your Apps" section of the [Twitter Developer website](http://developer.twitter.com/). Once you've registered your site as an app, click on My Access Token. That will give you a key/token that you can use to successfully authenticate.

---

Another thought is that Twitter is simply throttling *your* app. If this is the case, it's because you've got too much traffic and you're not caching the API results. Cache the results of the API for, say, an hour before fetching a new copy. Twitter will stop singling you out if you do this.

```
if(filemtime("cache.xml") < (int)$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] - 3600) {
    $data = file_get_contents("http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=username");
    file_put_contents("cache.xml", $data);
} else
    $data = file_get_contents("cache.xml");
```

Comment: Unbelieveably helpful! The cache thing did the trick..i searched the web everything for simple solution like that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Think your reg. exp. is too greedy.. believe it will match everything up until the last '< /'

try something like a non-greedy match:

```
/followers_count>(.*?)</
```

or match everything except '<'   :

```
/followers_count>([^<]*)</
```

Parsing the XML might be easier, and if you want to extract a lot from the xml, more "correct". But seems like overkill in your case.

Comment: I tried the XML method. It does not parse anything either on webserver. On localhost everything is fine.. This is weird, I checked if xml parser is loaded and yes it is. What could be that

Comment: See my comment on my post. As both methods work locally, I'm guessing that allow_url_fopen on the remote host is disabled. You need to turn error reporting on to debug.

Answer (score 0):

It's much better (more reliable and easier to maintain) to use an XML parser than to try to fetch bits with regular expressions.

Simply:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=username', null, true);

echo $xml->followers_count;
```

Comment: This code works on localhost, but not on my public host. What could be disabled on the host and denies it from working please?

Comment: Probably allow_url_fopen - http://uk.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen - try enabling all errors (error_reporting(E_ALL)) to get an error message, or you're going to be blindly debugging

Comment: I just added echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen') it returned 1. So thats enabled.. I guess

Comment: Is display_errors set to On? Are any errors shown for anything?

Comment: I set display errors on. Nothing shown, just blank .. I tried to know if allow_url_fopen and curl are active, yes both active. It just won't get any data on the webserver. on localhost yes . thats driving me crazy